# What is the cause of the artifacts of this convoluted signal?

Tags: python, numpy, convolution, artifacts

I am trying to find out the cause of the artifacts that appear after convolution, they are to be seen in the plot arround x = -.0016 and x= .0021 (please see the code below). I am convoluting the "lorentzian" function (or the derivative of the langevin function) which I define in the code, with 2 Dirac impulses in the function "ditrib".
I would appreciate your help. 
Thank you 
Here is my code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def Lorentzian(xx):
        if not hasattr(xx, '__iter__'):
            xx = [ xx ]
        res = np.zeros(len(xx))
        for i in range(len(xx)):
            x = xx[i]
            if np.fabs(x) < 0.1:
                res[i] =  1./3. - x**2/15. + 2.* x**4 / 189. - x**6/675. + 2.* x**8 / 10395. - 1382. * x**10 / 58046625. + 4. * x**12 / 1403325.
            else:
                res[i] = (1./x**2 - 1./np.sinh(x)**2)
        return res


    amp = 18e-3 
    a = 1/.61e3
    b = 5.5
    t_min = 0 
    dt = 1/5e6
    t_max = (10772) * dt
    t = np.arange(t_min,t_max,dt)
    x_min = -amp/b
    x_max = amp/b
    dx =  dt*(x_min-x_max)/(t_min-t_max)
    x = np.arange(x_min,x_max,dx)

    func1 = lambda x : Lorentzian(b*(x/a))

    def distrib(x):
        res = np.zeros(np.size(x))
        res[int(np.floor(np.size(x)/3))] = 1
        res[int(3*np.floor(np.size(x)/4))] = 3
        return res
    func2 = lambda x,xs : np.convolve(distrib(x), func1(xs), 'same')

    plt.plot(x, func2(x,x))
    plt.xlabel('x (m)')
    plt.ylabel('normalized signal')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the "pedestal" of func1

```
func1(x)[0], func1(x)[-1]
Out[7]: (0.0082945964013920719, 0.008297677313152443)
```

just subtract

```
func2 = lambda x,xs : np.convolve(distrib(x), func1(xs)-func1(x)[0], 'same')
```

gives a smooth convolution curve

depending on the result you want you may have to add it back in after, weighted by the Dirac sum

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help, I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you, it worked ! Can you please explain to me why one should do that ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: when you convlove a Dirac Impulse with a constant you get a step, Ideally you would just use all of the "lorentzian" instead of hacking the "pedestal of the finite range - but since it's defined on +/- infinity...